# add data from txt file to mysql column by column (php- PDO)

Tags: php, pdo, txt

I have a `TXT` file with no punctuation between them. I would like to shred this file by the table column widths in the database and save it.

Let me tell you this step by step…

1. I’m creating a table in the database with my `tabloolustur.php` page. The column numbers and column widths of the tables I create will not be the same.
2. There are no punctuation marks between the `TXT` file data. First, I want to split the TXT file rows by column width.

   ```
   $result = $baglanti->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM customers where Field NOT IN('id')");

   $result->execute();
   $colcount = $result->columnCount()-1;

   $columLen = array();

   foreach($result as $key => $col){

      preg_match('/\d+/', $col['Type'], $len);
      $len = (isset($len[0]))? $len[0] : '';  
      $fieldname = $col['Field'];            
      $columLen[$fieldname]  = $len;  

   }
   ```

   For this, I get the number of columns and column widths with the code.
3. Then, I separate the data with commas with the following function.

   ```
   function txtBol($metin, $genislik){
       $parcala=array();

       foreach ($genislik  as $sutunadi => $lenght)
       {
           $parcala[$sutunadi] = substr($metin, 0, $lenght);
           $metin = substr($metin, $lenght);

       }
   return $parcala;
   }
   ```
4. I also get column names with the following code. (ps: to use in a query)

   ```
   $KolAdi = $baglanti->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM customers  where Field NOT IN('id')");
   $KolAdi->execute();
   $colonAdi= $KolAdi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
   $colonAdi=implode(',', $colonAdi);
   ```

   It prints the data i split correctly when printing it to the screen. So far, so good. But I can’t create the right query with PDO. How should I create the query? (ps: Table column names and column widths are not the same. There will be different numbers and width columns for each table)
   I would appreciate it if you could help. I proceeded by implementing some solutions from your site.

`Table`:

| id | name | cev1 | cev2 | cev3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MARTIN EDEN | AAAAAA | BBBBB | CCCC |

`txt`:

```
MARTIN EDEN........AAAAAABBBBBDDDD
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some sample data and the structure of the table it is to be put in.

Comment: The number of table columns and column widths can change. so I didn't want to give a single table structure either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a valid PDO connection in $PDO, you can do the whole job like this.
It reads the column data once and uses that to create a query to prepare and a regular expression to extract the data.

```
$table = 'customer';
$txtFile = 'cust.txt';

// No need to prepare this since there's no untrusted data here.
$result = $pdo->query("show columns from `$table` where Field <> 'id'");

// Get column names and widths in arrays
while($columns = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $colNames[] = $columns['Field'];
    preg_match('/\d+/', $columns['Type'], $len);
    $colLengths[] = $len[0]??'';
}
// Create regex to extract data from lines:
// Looks like this: /(.{20})(.{10})(.{5})/
$regex = '/(.{'.implode('})(.{',$colLengths).'})/u';

// Create skeleton query with table name and field names and placeholders
// Looks like this: INSERT customer (name,addr1,postcode) VALUES (?,?,?)
$query = "INSERT $table (`".implode('`,`', $colNames).'`) VALUES ('.str_repeat('?,', count($colNames)-1).'?)';

// Read text file
if ($fileData = file($txtFile)) {
    // Prepare the query only once
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    foreach ($fileData as $row) {
        // Get the data using the regex from above
        preg_match($regex, $row, $rowData);
        // Remove the first row of the regex matches - see PHP manual for why
        array_shift($rowData);
        // Now execute the prepared query using the data extracted by the regex.
        $stmt->execute($rowData);
    }
}
```

Note that this codes assumes that the table consists of a series of contiguous columns from which it can extract column widths, and no other columns except `id`, which it ignores. If your actual table structure is different you'll need to modify the `SHOW COLUMNS` query to omit those columns, or modify the code that extracts the column data to extract only the relevant columns.

{Edit]
Updated the code to include `/u` UTF-8 modifier on the regex, and to wrap the column names in the INSERT query in back ticks.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly how I wanted it.

Comment: There is a small problem. Although the charset is utf8, when saving to the database, the letters İ,ı,Ö,ö,Ş,ş,Ü,ü,Ğ,ğ, '?' saves as. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Adding the UTF-8 modifier to the end of the regex should work (`$regex = '/(.{'.implode('})(.{',$colLengths).'})/u';`. This works on my system, but I couldn't make it display the `?` without the modifier. I use a UTF8 character set on my database by default. You should check that you have a UTF8 character set on your database.

Comment: Dear Tangential Perpendicular Solution I tried your suggestion but it didn't work on my system. it gave the following error. Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: @Martineden Adding the `/u` modifier won't affect the SQL syntax. Most likely you have a column name in your table that clashes with a MySQL keyword. I have updated the code above to wrap column names in backticks that should deal with this. Note that I run this on my development system with a limited set of test data. I am not in a position to debug this thoroughly for your environment without a comprehensive set of test data and tables. That's a different task and [so] is not the place.

Comment: Dear @Tangential Perpendicular
I changed the table column names, I tried the updated code but I got the same error.  You are also right in what you said. Thank you very much for your help. you are great

Comment: dear @Tangentially Perpendicular.  when you print the first line to the database, the first character is '?' it prints. on the first line, the sorting is broken. But it accurately records the next lines. when I print to the screen iimage: https://www.hizliresim.com/shc1c5k
When I print to the database image: https://www.hizliresim.com/tjx74n8

Comment: It looks like your file has a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). UTF-8 files permit it but don't require it. You can remove it with Notepad++ or other tools (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32986445/14853083)), or you can modify the code above to remove it from the first line before you process the file (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248518/14853083))

Comment: dear @Tangentially Perpendicular, your solution suggestion worked. I thank you for your help. You are great

Answer (score -1):

you can create a table like this and you don't need to check a number of fields by rows
let me know if this useful

CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`row_id` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`row_field_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Index of ',
`row_value` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

Comment: This is not relevant. The OPs problem is not with creating a table, but with creating a prepared query to match an unknown table structure.

Comment: can you share the table structure you prepared? based on this we can prepare the queries to execute
thank you